# Inconsistent Shading and Separation in Model's Appearance

Tags: modeling, lighting, shadows

I'm currently facing an issue with the shading of my model, which results in inconsistent shadows and lighting on different sides. It appears as if the two halves of the model are visually separated, even though they are supposed to be one cohesive piece. And I'm not quite sure how to fix it.

Imagine viewing my model from various angles. On one side, the shadows and highlights appear accurately and create a realistic three-dimensional effect. However, when looking from the other side, the shading seems inverted in some weird way, making it seem like the model has been split into two disconnected parts. In the image below you can clearly see that area around the nose and the neck is affected the most.

Do you have any insights, suggestions, or potential solutions to this issue?

[image: Weird Shading]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lecHw.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a mirror modifier on the object and if so have you made sure that there's no internal face between the halves?

Comment: This looks like an NPR shader set-up with some explicit influence from mesh-normals? If so, we need to see your shader tree, I think.. Check for consistent normals across the surface of your mesh

Comment: I have no mirror modifier and no internal face between the halves. I've tried to take as good pictures as possible of the node tree.